# Переименовать файлы на SD карте. Андроид приложение

Tags: android, файлы, storage

Никак не получается переименовать файл на SD карте из своего приложения. Устройство хуавей андроид 8. Разрешения на запись и чтение есть. Использую такую форму:

```
oldfile.renameTo(newfile)
```

Плюс ко всему прочему проверка:

```
oldfile.canWrite();
```

возвращает false. Уточню, файлы расположенные на устройстве спокойно переименывает, проблемы только с картой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии Android 4.4 приложениям запрещен доступ к редактированию содержимого SD карты через класс `File`. Вместо этого предлагается использовать [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=ru). Storage Access Framework умеет работать с SD картой начиная с Android 5.0 (на 4.4 редактировать содержимое SD карты официально нельзя). Можно использовать `Intent.Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` чтобы дать пользователю выбрать папку:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Результат выбора придет в `onActivityResult`. Сначала можно проверить, действительно ли пользователь выбрал нужную папку. Для этого можно вручную соорудить tree Uri из абсолютного пути файла и потом проверить, действительно ли в интенте пришел этот tree Uri. Потом нужно получить разрешение на работу с этой папкой через `getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermssion()` и потом можно использовать класс `DocumentFile` чтобы получить список файлов в папке и класс `DocumentsContract`, чтобы переименовать требуемый файл:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!= null && data.getData() != null){
        Uri treeUri = data.getData();
        int takeFlags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION;
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);
        DocumentFile folder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
        DocumentFile fileToRename = folder.listFiles()[0];
        try{
            DocumentsContract.renameDocument(getContentResolver(), fileToRename.getUri(), "top.txd");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException exception){

        }
        getContentResolver().releasePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**Важное уточнение: в следующей версии Android 11 доступ даже к внутреннему хранилищу через File будет закрыт. Придется использовать Storage Access Framework и для внутреннего хранилища.**

Comment: Файлы я получаю через поставщик контента. Переименовать надо папку с несколькими файлами. Саму папку получаю из абсолютного пути файла.

Comment: Обновил ответ (пример с папкой)

Comment: Спасибо. Конечно не совсем то, но буду ковырять дальше это направление.